# Android Application (Timer help)

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application that allow users to answer questions.

I am trying to include a timer in which after 5-10 sec if the user didn't answer the question the page will automatically move to the next page/activity

how do i do it?

Edited: I pasted the below code on every of my questions page. however when the user click next button to move to a new page the timer does not reset the countdown timer and instead the activity/page is restarted.

Example 
i am on page 1. i click next afew time to move to page 4.
15sec is up and page 2 activity is started.. instead of the timer restarting the count from 0sec in page 4 and moving to page 5.

pardon me for my english. hope you understand..

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...
 // 15 Sec move to next page if question not answer.
        new Handler ().postDelayed(new Runnable ()
        {

        public void run ()
          {
            moveToNextPage ();
          }

        private void moveToNextPage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionPage.this, Question_page2.class);

            //Start CreateAccountActivity 2nd PAGE
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }, 15000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler.postdelayed for this:

```
new Handler ().postDepayed(new Runnable ()
{

public void run ()
  {
    moveToNextPage ();
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Where should I put the code? Sry. I new to android programming.

Comment: In this case the `onResume` method should be the best choice, because then you can be sure, that the user doesn't lose time, because something else was still loading.

Comment: hi i have some problem using the code you have given. please see my edited post.

Comment: Make a global boolean set to true. When the user answers before he ran out of time set the boolean to false. Place the boolean insde a if-statement before `moveToNextPage ();

Comment: Sry. But can you give an example how to do that?